# Automatizar um script .sh

Tags: shell-script, automatização

Eu tenho um Shell Script (.sh) e preciso automatiza-lo. Alguém poderia me ajudar??

Esse script, copia dados de uma pasta e cola (convertendo em outro formato) em outro diretório, roda um script em Python para plotagem de dados, e atualiza as informações obtidas em uma página da internet.

Para copiar e colar arquivos de uma pasta em outra, o script lê o nome do arquivo, o qual contem a data inserida, e executa os outros comandos a partir daí.

Os dados a serem copiados são de dois dias atrás (já que não tenho disponível os dados das últimas 24h)

O problema é que eu preciso mudar manualmente a data, todos os dias.

Preciso encontrar uma jeito de automatizar esse processo de maneira que não precise fazer essa atualização da data manualmente.

Preciso que o script além de atualizar a data automaticamente, rode também em uma determinada hora do dia e que me retorne uma mensagem de erro caso não encontre dados na pasta para serem copiados.

Sou nova em programação e por isso estou com dificuldade em encontrar a melhor maneira para fazer isso.

Segue abaixo o codigo que estou usando:

```
!/bin/bash

date="2017-11-17"

year=`date +"%Y"`
previous_year=`date +"%Y" -d "-1 year"`

h4=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/SCRIPTS/

dir=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP/ 

cd /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/L1.5/2017/

cp CAL_LID_L15_Exp-Beta-V3-40.${date}T*.hdf  /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP

for i in ${dir}*.hdf; do ${h4}h4tonccf_nc4 $i; done

python ${h4}CalipsoLatLonTimeLoop_TimTrack.py

#Uploading the data to WEB server
rsync -u -z -v -e "ssh -p 8222" /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/PICS/${year}* update@140.203.204.132:/home/www/html/rt/PICS/${year}/
rsync -u -z -v -e "ssh -p 8222" /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/PICS/${previous_year}* update@140.203.204.132:/home/www/html/rt/PICS/${previous_year}/
```

Comment: Eventualmente arranja um nome melhor para a script (uma script chamada script é como um cão chamado cão)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos lá...

Bem, irei tentar auxiliar a resolver esses empecilhos porém se tivesse postado o código seria mais fácil...

**DATA**

Utilizando esse código concatenado a string onde a data é inserida irá pegar a data do dia atual.

```
date +%d/%m/%Y
```

**AUTOMATIZAÇÃO**

Para automatizar a execução desse script basta utulizar o cron.
Para adicionar uma tarefa ao cron é preciso que você abra com um editor de texto qualquer (se estiver usando interface gráfica Gnome, e se tiver instalado, poderá utilizar o gedit, ou se e estiver em moda caracter o vim ,vim, nano, pipe como preferir) o arquivo /etc/crontab e agendar, definindo o mês/dia/hora em que o comando devera ser executado. Para que a ferramenta cron funcione não é necessário reiniciá-la.

Para que o agendamento funcione é necessário que siga um padrão, um formato ao qual deve se respeitar. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
[minutos] [horas] [dias do mês] [mês] [dias da semana] [usuário] [comando]


31 18 1 * * root run-parts --report /etc/cron.montly
|   | | | |   |    |
|   | | | |   |     \_Comando que será executado
|   | | | |   |
|   | | | |    \_ UID que executará o comando
|   | | | |
|   | | | \_ Dia da semana (0-7)
|   | | |
|   | |  \_ Mês (1-12)
|   | |
|   |  \_ Dia do Mês (1-31)
|   |
|   \_ Hora
|
\_ Minuto
```

**UPDATE #1**

Ah entendi, bem também é possível pegar uma data anterior ou posterior a do dia atual. Siga esse exemplo:

```
ontem=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%d/%m/%Y")
echo "O backup foi realizado $ontem"
```

**UPDATE #2**

Sem problemas, estou aqui para te ajudar. O cron é um agendador de tarefas do sistema operacional, você deve colocar a execução do seu script como uma tarefa dele. O jeito mais fácil de editar o cron é:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Ao adicionar uma linha como essa por exemplo:

```
* 1 * * * root /caminho/do/seu/script.sh
```

Será executado o "script.sh" a cada hora.

**UPDATE #3**

Segue o código modificado por mim porém **não** testado.

```
!/bin/bash

ontem=$(date --date="2 days ago" +"%Y-%m-%d");

date=$ontem

year=date +"%Y" previous_year=date +"%Y" -d "-1 year"
h4=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/SCRIPTS/
dir=/mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP/
cd /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/L1.5/$year/
cp CAL_LID_L15_Exp-Beta-V3-40.${date}T*.hdf /mnt/raid/CALIPSO/DATA/NETCDF_TEMP

for i in ${dir}*.hdf; do ${h4}h4tonccf_nc4 $i; done

python ${h4}CalipsoLatLonTimeLoop_TimTrack.py
```

**UPDATE #4**

Correção no código.

**UPDATE#5**

Correção da ilustração da tabela do cron.

Good luck!

Comment: Oii..Obrigada pela ajuda, mas eu ainda estou com algumas duvidas:
So o comando que vc deu (date +%d/%m/%Y) ja basta?
Eu nao expliquei da primeira vez, me desculpa, mas os dados a serem copiados e colados nao sao do dia corrente mas sim, de dois dias atras. Por isso, hoje por exemplo eu rodo esse script para os dados do dia 18. Os dados do dia 19 e de hoje (dia 20) ainda nao estao disponiveis.
Por isso, acredito, que um outro comando precisa ser executado levando sempre em conta a data de dois dias anteriores, nao? Eu vou atualizar o post com o codigo que estou usando

Comment: Mais uma coisa, quanto ao cron, esse comando que voce passou nao entraria nesse script entao? Ele seria rodado separadamente?

Desculpa pelas explicacoes quebradas, como eu disse sou nova nessa aera e estou com dificuldades para entender como as coisas funcionam...e obrigada pela ajuda!

Comment: Dei uma complementada, dá uma olhadinha.... Se precisar de mais ajuda só postar aqui ou me chamar no inst luigibredaa

Comment: Entao, no lugar do date="2017-11-17", eu coloco:
ontem=$(date --date="yesterday" +"%d/%m/%Y")
echo "O backup foi realizado $ontem"
Nesse caso, o date --date, ja esta se referindo a data de dois dias atras? Ou eu preciso especificar isso de outra maneira?
Quanto ao cron, agora eu entendi! Obrigada! =)

Comment: Que bom que entendeu a questão do cron... mexi no teu código, consegue testar e me avisar? Não esqueça de avaliar minha resposta.

Comment: Testei e nao funcionou...pelo o que eu entendi do erro, o programa esta tentando pegar os dados de ontem (que ainda nao estao disponiveis) e nao de dois dias atras...PS: resposta avaliada!

Comment: Obrigado, só trocar por --date="2 days ago"

Comment: Obrigada! mas continua dando erro: cp: cannot stat `CAL_LID_L15_Exp-Beta-V3-40.2017/11/18T*.hdf': No such file or directory
Fail to open the HDF4 file with Hopen.(hdf4_file.cpp:56)
Error to call h4cf_open. 
The program exits abnormally

Comment: O erro que deu é por que ele não conseguiu copiar o arquivo ele não existe. Verifique isso.. a questão da data funcionou porém os arquivos estão com nome diferentes da data de anteontem ao que parece.

Comment: Quando eu rodo o codigo antigo, com o date="2017-11-17", ele vai...sao os mesmos diretorios e os mesmo arquivos, por isso nao estou entendendo esse erro. O nome do arquivo nao muda, soh muda a data

Comment: Já sei... a data que estamos criando automaticamente é separada por / e a sua é por -. Irei atualizar o post.

Comment: Funcionou!!! Muitissimo obrigada! =)

Comment: Não por isso, precisando me chame no insta. @luigibredaa

Comment: Acho que tem dois espaços a mais nas setas dos seus desenhos. Minutos está certo, mas tudo o que vem depois deveria estar dois caracteres à esquerda. Causou uma pequena confusão a primeira vez que fui ler, pois `Dia da Semana` está apontando para o `UID`, e o que está sendo apontado pelo `UID` está apontando para o comando a ser executado

Comment: Editado, obrigado Jefferson Quesado.